# Open chrome from osx terminal with specific named tab target

Tags: macos, google-chrome, terminal, tabs

I have implemented a file watcher that whenever a file is saved from a given watched folder it will open google chrome from the terminal like this `/usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" '${url}'`

The problem is that If I save the file two times or more than one file, it will open many tabs in my chrome instance with the same url.

What I want to do is for it to refresh it instead.  Similar as what would happen when you do `<a href="someurl.com" target="somenamedtab">this will open in somenamedtab</a>`

Is there any way to run `/usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" '${url}'` but specifying which named tab?